# XenServer 6.5 Trying to launch VMs from Local SR

Tags: command-line, xen

Let me being by saying I am new to Xen Server, I’m come for the telecom/networking world, but now I find myself managing servers. With that being said I am looking for assistance with setting up a local SR that will hold ISO’s where I can launch VMs.

This is what I have done so far, not necessarily in this order.

1. Scanned the partition, looking for space:

   ```
   [root@xenserver-antaira ~]# pvscan PV /dev/sda3
   VG VG_XenStorage-a6742c6f-6ec8-8299-46ad-c9eaffeed2d8  
   lvm2 [3.63 TB / 1.52 TB free]
   Total: 1 [3.63 TB] / in use: 1 [3.63 TB] / in no VG: 0 [0   ]
   ```
2. Check the VG location:

   ```
   [root@xenserver-antaira ~]# dir /dev/VG_XenStorage-a6742c6f-6ec8-8299-46ad-c9eaffeed2d8/
   MGT  VHD-65b01e06-436a-4a18-b929-aa24f30a660e  VHD-f9f374c9-f010-46a4-8d34-f7eaef24381d
   ```
3. I created the volume:

   ```
   ACTIVE  '/dev/VG_XenStorage-a6742c6f-6ec8-8299-46ad-c9eaffeed2d8/LinuxISO' [50.00 GB] inherit
   ```
4. Then I created the files system:
   [root@xenserver-antaira ~]# df -Th
   /dev/mapper/VG_XenStorage--a6742c6f--6ec8--8299--46ad--c9eaffeed2d8-LinuxISO
             ext3     50G  1.1G   46G   3% /mnt/LinuxISO
5. Created the storage repository:

   ```
   xe sr-create name-label=ISO_Linux type=iso device-config:legacy_mode=true device-config:location=/var/xen/LinuxISO/
   ```
6. Created the storage folder and transferred ISO:

   ```
   [root@xenserver-antaira /]# dir /mnt/LinuxISO
   lost+found  ubuntu-18.04.4-live-server-amd64.iso
   ```
7. Verified the mapping:

   ```
   [root@xenserver-antaira /]# ls -lhs /var/xen/LinuxISO
   0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 13 Mar 18 16:46 LinuxISO -> /mnt/LinuxISO
   ```
8. Added the following to /etc/rc.local

   ```
   Mount ISO
   vgchange -a y
   mount /dev/VG_XenStorage-a6742c6f-6ec8-8299-46ad-c9eaffeed2d8/LinuxISO /mnt/LinuxISO
   ```
9. I have verified the ISO in the /mnt/LinuxISO folder

   ```
   cd /mnt/LinuxISO
   dir
   lost+found  ubuntu-18.04.4-live-server-amd64.iso
   ```
10. I have verified the mapping

    ```
    [root@xenserver-antaira /]# ls -lhs /var/xen/LinuxISO
    0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 13 Mar 18 16:46 LinuxISO -> /mnt/LinuxISO
    ```

The problem, when checking the SR I don’t see any ISOs under the storage tab. When I go to add a new virtual disk, is shows the SR as being full. I’m lost here, can anyone give me some assistance

Answer (score 1):

[root@xenserver-antaira ~]# pvscan
  PV /dev/sda3   VG VG_XenStorage-a6742c6f-6ec8-8299-46ad-c9eaffeed2d8   lvm2 [3.63 TB / 1.46 TB free]
  Total: 1 [3.63 TB] / in use: 1 [3.63 TB] / in no VG: 0 [0   ]

- Created LVM Space for ISO Repository
  lvcreate -L 50G -n Linux_Storage VG_XenStorage-a6742c6f-6ec8-8299-46ad-c9eaffeed2d8
- Activated 
  vgchange -a y 
  ACTIVE    '/dev/VG_XenStorage-a6742c6f-6ec8-8299-46ad-c9eaffeed2d8/Linux_Storage' [50.00 GB] inherit
- Created the files system
  mkfs.ext3 /dev/VG_XenStorage-a6742c6f-6ec8-8299-46ad-c9eaffeed2d8/Linux_Storage
- Mount the ISO Repository and created a link to default folder
  mkdir /mnt/linux_repo
  mkdir /var/xen/linux_repo
  ln -s /mnt/linux_repo /var/xen/linux_repo
- Verified link
  ls -l /var/xen/linux_repo
  lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 15 Mar 23 19:20 linux_repo -> /mnt/linux_repo
- Edited /etc/rc.local
  vgchange -a y
  mount /dev/VG_XenStorage-a6742c6f-6ec8-8299-46ad-c9eaffeed2d8/Linix_Storage /mnt/linux_repo
- At this point I rebooted the server
- Then create the repo 
  xe sr-create name-label=LINUX_ISOs type=iso device-config:location=/mnt/linux_repo/ device-config:legacy_mode=true content-type=iso

Once completed I check in the XenCenter and my SR was in place.

I used WinSCP to transfer my ISO to the /mnt/linux_repo folder. I hit rescan and boom, my ISO was there.